# Are questions about DVD's of movie/TV-shows on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions on movie DVD's, whether related to their content, or any technical details such as format, region, etc. (sample questions below), on topic for movies.SE, even though they may be specific and answerable as per SE guidelines?

Sample questions:

**For Content**

1. Does the Ultimate/Collectors/Steelbook edition of the "X" movie's BluRay release, have this specific "Y" extra that I'm interested in?

**Technical**

2. Are the extras on the "X" edition of "Y" movie in HD or SD?
3. Is the SD content on "X" disc in anamorphic wide-screen or letterbox?
4. Are the discs in this specific "X" edition of "Y" movie region-free?

Comment: From the example question, it should be off topic but lets see what other say.

Answer (score -2):

My opinion on the matter is the same as my criteria for what's Trivia:

That's fine as long as I can't find it on Google on the first couple of pages.

But I suspect all these kinds of questions could easily be answered by looking up the DVD on Amazon / IMDb / eBay / Google Image pictures of the covers.

Comment: Even if you can find it on Google, you can't assume that those pages on Google will always exist.  If the answer gets posted to SE, and those other pages disappear, then the answer will still be available on SE.